# Try / Except indentation error

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I have been creating a program that sorts files and I need a try to catch an error

here is the code:

```
    try: 
        shutil.move(path, directory)
    except OSError:
        print 'ERROR: File name already in use'
        quit()
```

but when I try this the error:

```
    except OSError:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: I have a suggestion, indent your code!

Comment: `try` and `except` have to be at the same level of indentation.

Comment: You need to post the context of the code if your try and except is at the same level of indentation.

Comment: Please read a python tutorial, indentation is important in python because it groups blocks of code. Review your code your indentation is wrong before the except keyword.

Comment: check if `try` is in the same indentation level as the start of the block of code above it.

Comment: Also check you haven't mixed tabs and spaces. Even if it looks the same, that can cause problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pasting your code into a text editor that shows whitespace, I see you mix tabs and spaces.

[image]

This is generally a bad idea - although a tab character may look like four spaces in your editor and on Stack Overflow, Python actually interprets it as a variable number of spaces between 1 and 8! (See [Lexical Analysis - Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) for more detail.)

Rewrite your code so it uses only spaces.

```
    try: 
        shutil.move(path, directory)
    except OSError:
        print 'ERROR: File name already in use'
        quit()
```